# should I set images to no index to avoid crawl budget limit

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, crawl-errors

Most of my posts in search console are showing

> URL is on Google, but has issues

I checked Crawl Page more info section and found out the blog post with many images show `other error` and the image link as shown below:

[image]

## **Important Notes:**

- Posts with few images crawled successfully and show "**URL is available to Google**"
- The same post with many images show "**URL is available to Google**"  without any error when I performed "Page Live Test"

[image]

I understood it's because of the **Crawl Budget limit**!
So my questions are

- Is "`URL is on Google, but has issues`" error will affect my ranking on google?
- Should I set images to no index to avoid crawl budget limit
- Although I only have around 500 posts, I would like to know why I am facing crawl budget issue)

Comment: Do you know what the "other error" from your screenshot is?  Does search console give you more info if you click on that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jetpack CDN then it can be a problem with this. You problem is We cannot complete this request, remote server returned an unexpected status code (400).

Comment: Yes, I am using JetPack CDN, what should I do now!

Comment: Contact directly at https://jetpack.com/contact-support/ to further assist you this. They solved for me the same issue.